# Xcode Confusing NSMutableArray with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am writing an iOS application, which required me to use some NSMutableArray's. Before, I was using NSMutableDictionary (under the same variable name), but I commented out code that has to do with the dictionary. Now, when using NSMutableArray, I am calling the method -addObject:. However, Xcode keeps giving me a warning saying that "NSMutableDictionary may not respond to -addObject:". However, I have checked, and checked again, and again, that the definition and allocation both say NSMutableArray not NSMutableDictionary. I even tried commenting out NSMutableDictionary code in my class, however the warning persists. The application runs fine and can execute the methods successfully, however the warnings are annoying. I am using Snow Leopard 10.6.8, Xcode 4.0.2. I tried restarting Xcode, but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

.h:

```
NSArray *array;
NSMutableArray *mutableArray;
```

.m

```
//allocation
mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//line where I get warning
[mutableArray addObject:someObj];
```

This happens with every array I tested with.

Comment: If you post some code, it will be easier to track down. Are you sure that you also have changed your variable types in the header?

Comment: Are you sure you changed the right .h file?

Comment: Yep. I checked multiple times.

Comment: Did you make that a setter method and use NSMutableDictionary there instead?

Comment: Okay, here's what happened. There was one version of the .m, and two versions of the .h. The .m was importing the wrong version of the .h-the one I wasn't updating. Therefor, when I updated the .h, it didn't do anything. After I deleted the wrong .h and added the right .h to the project, everything worked fine - the warnings went away and changes in the .h reflected in the .m.

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? If it is, and these are the only points that the array's are used, then there is no problem with your code. You may want to try making a new .h and .m file, and add in your code step by step to make sure everything works.

Comment: Yes, this is my code. What happened is that Xcode told me the .h was missing. Instead of clicking re-save, I clicked on Save As... and saved it in the directory of the project. However, my .m was somewhere else, with another copy of the .h. I just moved the .m to the project directory as well, then deleted the old version of the .h.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay, here's what happened. There was one version of the .m, and two versions of the .h. The .m was importing the wrong version of the .h-the one I wasn't updating. Therefor, when I updated the .h, it didn't do anything. After I deleted the wrong .h and added the right .h to the project, everything worked fine - the warnings went away and changes in the .h reflected in the .m.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I'm not at my workstation at the moment, but try >man xcodeindex, it can clean out the index for you. (if it's still in 10.6)</strike>

Enter Xcode's preferences, and find the Locations pane. In it, you have the "Derived Data", containing all sorts of non-primary information about your project. You can navigate to it by clicking the little arrow to the right of the path.

Close all your Xcode projects and quit Xcode. Now, delete the contents of the Derived Data folder, and reopen your project. Xcode should (pretty quickly) regenerate the index.

Comment: Yes, I am still in 10.6. What do you mean by ">man xcodeindex"?

Comment: See my edit above - xcodeindex seems to be gone from the latest Xcode.